# Dynamically creating JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I was wondering if it was at all possible to create buttons on based on a number given by the user?
For example, if I press a button, and I have 5 options, I want the application to create 5 buttons, and display them. All the buttons would have a number on them, and every time you pressed that button, it's value would decrease by 1 (the value on that particular button). When the number reaches 0, the button would be `.setEnabled(false)`. Since all the buttons would have pretty much the same function, I could call 1 `ActionListner`, was just wondering it it was at all possible to dynamically create as many buttons as I need, and display them all.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use a simple loop.

Comment: Could you show an example? I don't know how I could create a loop without the compiler complaining of already existing variables.

Comment: `List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>(); for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { buttons.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1))); }`

Comment: @user2388169: if you're having trouble creating a loop, then show us your attempt and the errors. I've found that's the best way of figuring out what you most need help with, and is always better than asking folks to spoon feed you code.

Comment: Create `ArrayList<JButton>` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. You can make something like:

```
public ArrayList<JButton> list = new ArrayList<JButton>();
//...

public void setButtons(int nButtons){     //nButtons=number of buttons you'd need
  for (int i =0; i<nButtons; i++)
  { 
   this.list.add( new Jbutton("here include whatever you want for your button"));
  }
 }
```

And you'd have an `ArrayList` with all your buttons. When you don't need them in the JPanel, you could just hide them.

Comment: Thanks! Surprise question, do you think it'd be possible to, when done with their use, dispose of them, and create all new buttons on the same `JPanel` without having any issues? Or should I save that for a new question here on Stackoverflow?

Comment: You could always hide the buttons : )

Comment: And hiding the buttons wouldn't interfere with the panel at all? For instance, it wouldn't put the buttons in a weird looking place because the other buttons used to be there? I remember I accidentally called a `JLabel` twice in one of my programs, and it made the whole UI look funky until I fixed it. And as a final question, there'd be no way to delete those buttons rather then hide them? Or would they all go away when the program closed, and could just be recreated when needed? Thanks again for your answers :)

Comment: @user2388169: start coding. Asking yourself about all the things that could happen won't make you go very far.

Comment: @user2388169 you can always make a new method for hiding the buttons without interfering in the looks. For example, you could set a code that moves button3 to the position of button2 if button2.setVisible is false

Comment: @JBNizet I understand that, but Im about to hit a large part in this project im working on, and would hate to have to resign it half way in. Just making sure I can cover my tracks when I start getting into it :)

Comment: @user2388169 thanks to you. Work hard and good luck with the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide with setVisible(false) the buttons once they are used.